# Key generation algorithm in Riak

Tags: key, server-side, riak

Riak has an API, which allows to create a record and unique key would be generated on server.
What algorithm is used for server-side key generation in Riak?
Is the length configurable? Is it securely random?
Can it be used as authentication token?

Answer (score 1):

The generated key is the base 62 representation of the sha hash of an erlang reference and the current timestamp.  The code is available [here](https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/develop/src/riak_core_util.erl#L215-L221)

```
unique_id_62() ->
    Rand = sha(term_to_binary({make_ref(), os:timestamp()})),
    <<I:160/integer>> = Rand,
    integer_to_list(I, 62).
```

Personally, I would not consider this to be sufficiently secure to use as a persistent authentication token.